# Can't get a function to work (Node JS, Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add a search functionality to my app. I wrote two functions, one is working and the other doesn't. I tried to figure it out but had no luck.

**This is the working function:**

```
// Add Search Functionility
router.get('/:searchTerm', ensureLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  let searchTerm = req.params.searchTerm;
  let regex = new RegExp(searchTerm.replace(/[w]/g, ":a"), 'g');
  let loggedUser = req.user.id;

  User.findById(loggedUser).exec()
  .then(foundUser => {
    if (foundUser.role != 'admin') {
      if (isNaN(searchTerm)) {
        User.findById(loggedUser).populate({path: 'permits', match: {'name': regex, isAuth: true}}).exec()
        .then(populatedUser => res.json(populatedUser.permits))
        .catch(err => res.send(err));
      } else {
        User.findById(loggedUser).populate({path: 'permits', match: {'num': regex, isAuth: true}}).exec()
        .then(populatedUser => res.json(populatedUser.permits))
        .catch(err => res.send(err));
      }
    } else {
      if (isNaN(searchTerm)) {
        Permit.find({'name': regex, isAuth: true}).populate('authBy', 'username').sort({date: 'desc'}).exec()
        .then(foundPermits => res.json(foundPermits))
        .catch(err => res.send(err));
      } else {
        Permit.find({'num': regex, isAuth: true}).populate('authBy', 'username').sort({date: 'desc'}).exec()
        .then(foundPermits => res.json(foundPermits))
        .catch(err => res.send(err));
      }
    }
  })
});
```

**And this is the not working function:**

```
// Add Search Functionility
router.get('/:searchTerm', ensureLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  let searchTerm = req.params.searchTerm;
  let regex = new RegExp(searchTerm.replace(/[w]/g, ":a"), 'g');
  let loggedUser = req.user.id;

  function searchPermitsBy(query) {
    User.findById(loggedUser).exec()
      .then(foundUser => {
        if (foundUser.role != 'admin') {
          User.findById(loggedUser).populate({path: 'permits', match: {query: regex, isAuth: true}}).exec()
          .then(populatedUser => res.json(populatedUser.permits))
          .catch(err => res.send(err));
        } else {
          Permit.find({query: regex, isAuth: true}).populate('authBy', 'username').sort({date: 'desc'}).exec()
          .then(foundPermits => res.json(foundPermits))
          .catch(err => res.send(err));
        }
      })
    .catch(err => res.send(err));
  }
  isNaN(searchTerm) ? searchPermitsBy('name') : searchPermitsBy('num');
});
```

Can you help me locate the issue? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `query` variable.
You cannot directly add a key to json using variable.
You have to use
`json[varContainingKey]=value`

```
// Add Search Functionility
router.get('/:searchTerm', ensureLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  let searchTerm = req.params.searchTerm;
  let regex = new RegExp(searchTerm.replace(/[w]/g, ":a"), 'g');
  let loggedUser = req.user.id;

  function searchPermitsBy(query) {
    User.findById(loggedUser).exec()
      .then(foundUser => {

    //create match variable
        var match = {isAuth:true}

    //Add query to match variable
        match[query]=regex


        if (foundUser.role != 'admin') {
          User.findById(loggedUser).populate({path: 'permits', match: match}).exec()
          .then(populatedUser => res.json(populatedUser.permits))
          .catch(err => res.send(err));
        } else {
          Permit.find(match).populate('authBy', 'username').sort({date: 'desc'}).exec()
          .then(foundPermits => res.json(foundPermits))
          .catch(err => res.send(err));
        }
      })
    .catch(err => res.send(err));
  }
  isNaN(searchTerm) ? searchPermitsBy('name') : searchPermitsBy('num');
});
```